# How to generate 40-bit unique values randomly?

Tags: random, unique

I'd like to generate 40-bit values, which are unique and non [so easily] guessable.

How can I do it? Any suggestions?

-edit-
I'm interested in an algorithm, C# or Java would be the cherry in the top of the cake!

-edit2-
I'm able to store previous values but I wouldn't like to have to check the whole list everytime I generate a new number

Comment: what is your preference programming language?

Comment: C# or Java, but an algorithm in any language would be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform are you on? On unix-ish systems, just read 40bits from /dev/random (blocks if insufficient entropy is available) or /dev/urandom (doesn't block, but also produces lower-quality random numbers if entropy is limited).

Comment: Yes, they would be. Windows has its own random number generators built in, though the only method I can think of to access them in PHP is via the session name subsystem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file. Maybe there's a COM call or something you could do.

Answer (score 0):

get first 12 bit(upto max 4095) as day from first release of ur program(will be unique part), other 38 bit use from random system call/function.
so u have recheck last day only values for unique.
sorry, no way GRANT unique from non-predictable(random) value.

u  can use more part from date, upto seconds for example. u can shafle predictable(date) bits, but it will nto add security.

anyway u have to balance between unique check time/random quality. to increase speed of check, can use binary tree or other technics.

also  u can use timer value upto miliseconds.. for busy system it will be unique(if do thread lock+ 50ms sleep) and not so predictable in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score -1):

usign what? in general random =unqiue,so use random. or

date|md5sum|cut -b 4-9

something like that

Comment: That's not random. That's actually highly predictable. Also, random does NOT mean unique. It's entirely possible to randomly generate 5 million "heads" in a row via coin toss. Random? Yes. Likely? No.

Comment: Agree with Marc B, also it wouldn't work if I tried to generate the numbers in less than a second (I would get repeated numbers)

Comment: that was only posible answer for question in original state ;)